# Realm: Updating property slow

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my app the user can select multiple contacts in a collectionview. When he selects a cell the property "isSelected" on the corresponding object "contact" will be set to true and the collectionview refreshes the selected cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let contact: self.filteredContacts[indexPath.row]
      self.invertSelectionStatusOfContact(contact)
      self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}

func invertSelectionStatusOfContact(contact:Contact){

    try! self.realm.write {
        contact.isSelected = !contact.isSelected
    }
}
```

There is a delay from around 500ms which was much faster when I was using coredata. Is there something I can to to get more performance?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and after all I decided not to use `realm.write` dynamically (every time when user selects contact).

Instead of, I decided to keep references to my contacts objects in my ViewController and change property `isSelected`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let contact: self.filteredContacts[indexPath.row]
    contact.isSelected = !contact.isSelected
    self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}
```

Don't forget update your contact object with `realm.write()` when user is about to leave your ViewController.

The whole trick is use to `realm.write()` only once. Try to figure out when is good moment to do that.

**EDIT**
I don't think you could improve performance of Realm write transaction. It's definitely time-consuming, mostly because of file I/O.

Comment: But outside a write-transaction this causes a crash?  --> Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you cannot edit Realm Object outside `Write Transaction`. The point is to create new Realm Objects (`Contact()`) and use it. And then replace old one with new, updated one. It works for me. As far I remember using Swift you have to init new object with parameter: `updates:true` (if you use primary key). Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any troubles.

Comment: You have to make sure that your `Contact` object has a primary key in that case. Alternatively, you could also manage the changes to selection states in a dictionary. Batching writes to larger transactions is generally a very good idea with Realm.